# Is there a way to generate IPython docstrings on the fly?

Tags: python, ipython, dispatch, docstring

I like that IPython will fetch docstrings if I type `foo.bar?`

However, I may sometimes build the `foo.bar` method dynamically, using `foo.__getattr__`. I could conceivably also generate a docstring dynamically, perhaps in a magic method like `foo.__getdoc__`.

Does IPython provide any mechanism for doing this, such that it would discover and display docstrings built on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with IPython, IPython just reads the `__doc__` attribute of an object. If you dynamically create your objects in the `__getattr__` method you should just set their `__doc__` attribute as well and everything will work correctly in IPython.

Here is an example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A[%s]' % self.name

class Test(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        a = A(name)
        a.__doc__ = 'My a documentation'
        return a

In [11]: t = Test()
In [12]: t.foo
A[foo]
In [13]: t.foo?
Type:       A
String Form:A[foo]
Docstring:  My a documentation
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think IPython would call `__getattr__` for `t.foo(<TAB>` in the notebook, but apparently it does! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set `foo.__doc__ = "my doc string"`.